# Update a column using another column in the same table with two entries (Values) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a column `Product_Group` from a column called `Product` in the same table. This `Product` column has two entries, `Simple` or `Others`. i.e shown below in `Invoice` table:

[image: Invoice Table]

The issue I'm have is that if you look at Top_Level ID 10, 19, 21 and 31 has multiple entries and the Product are multiple as well (i.e Simple and Others).

What I want to achieve is that when I see Top_Level who has Simple and Others then update Product_Group Column to "Simple/Other"

[image: Final outcome]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only two groups, so you can use window functions, `min()` and `max()`:

```
select i.*,
       (case when min(product) over (partition by top_level) =
                  max(product) over (partition by top_level)
             then product
             else 'Other/Simple'
        end) as product_group
from invoices i;
```

You would want to use `min(product) over (partition by top_level)` if `product` could ever be `NULL`.

This approach does not generalize (easily) to more than two groups.  But it should work well in this situation.

EDIT:

If you actually want to update the column, just use a CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select i.*,
             (case when min(product) over (partition by top_level) =
                        max(product) over (partition by top_level)
                   then product
                   else 'Other/Simple'
              end) as new_product_group
      from invoices i
     )
update toupdate
    set product_group = new_product_group;
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Also, I have taken note on the NULLs so what I did is to filter by Product IS NOT NULL to update the table.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only 2 Product  then you could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT Top_Level, COUNT(DISTINCT Product) AS cnt
   FROM tab
   GROUP BY Top_Level
)
UPDATE t
SET Product_group = CASE WHEN cnt = 1 THEN t.Product ELSE 'Others/Simple' END;
FROM tab t
JOIN cte ctab
  ON c.Top_Level = t.Top_Level;
```

Comment: just tick sign on you left, side by side with the answer